# Some complex-number manipulation when calculating coefficients

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, complex-numbers

I am going through Sakurai's quantum mechanics, and at one point the solution to a problem says:

$(\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha)-i\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha))b+\cos(\beta)a=a$
$(\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha)+i\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha))a-\cos(\beta)b=b$

$a,b$ are the complex coefficients for some state, so we have:

$|a|^2+|b|^2=1$

What I don't understand is that from there he goes to:

$a=\cos(\frac{\beta}{2})e^{i\theta_a}$

For some $\theta_a$. I understand that you can write $a$ as $r e^{i\theta}$ for some $r,\theta$, but I dont see how he is able to get $r=\cos(\frac{\beta}{2})$. Where does this come from?

Comment: Isn't the solution to both simultaneous equations $a=b=0$ ? How can $a$ have a non-zero magnitude ?

Comment: @Amr Sorry, they should be normalised to $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$, not $0$. I have updated my question to fix that, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Would http://math.stackexchange.com/ be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic Sorry, I suppose it would be. Next time I will post the more mathematical questions there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result
$$ a=\cos(\frac{\beta}{2})e^{i\theta_a} $$
is simply a solution to the original set of two linear equations
$$ (\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha)-i\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha))b+\cos(\beta)a=a \\
(\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha)+i\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha))a-\cos(\beta)b=b$$
Those equations may be rewritten as
$$ \sin\beta \exp(-i\alpha) b = (1-\cos\beta) a\\
\sin\beta\exp(+i\alpha) a = (1+\cos\beta) b $$
I have only accumulated terms by using $\exp ix = \cos x + i\sin x$ and rearranged the terms. Now, divide the first equation by the second to get
$$\exp(-2i\alpha) \frac{b}{a} = \frac{a}{b} \frac {1-\cos\beta}{1+\cos\beta} $$
It means, using $1+\cos\beta = 2\cos^2 (\beta/2)$ etc., that
$$\frac{b^2}{a^2} =\exp(2i\alpha) \frac{\sin^2\beta}{\cos^2\beta} $$
Taking the square root,
$$\frac{b}{a} = \pm \exp(i\alpha) \tan\beta $$
The absolute value of this equation is
$$\left| \frac ba \right| = \tan\beta$$
because the ambiguous sign and the extra phase may be ignored. But because the ratio $b/a$ is $\sin\beta/\cos\beta$ and $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$, which is also obeyed by the sine and cosine, it follows that
$$|a|=\cos\beta,\quad |b|=\sin\beta$$
In fact, we were also able to derive that the relative phase of $b,a$ is $\pm\exp(i\alpha)$; it's plausible that only one of the signs is right and you may derive which one. The absolute phase isn't determined: you may always find another solution by multiplying $a,b$ by the same phase $\exp(i\gamma)$.

At any rate, because we know the absolute values of $a,b$, we may write them as the absolute values times some phases.

Comment: I assume that from the trig identity onwards it should be $\frac{\beta}{2}$ rather than $\beta$?  That's just a minor point though. Thank-you very much for putting the time into writing that, this helped me a lot.